# Redis Queues - How to resume

Tags: redis, queue

Let's suppose we have a list of tasks to be executed and some workers that pop items from that list.
If a worker crashes unexpectedly before finishing the execution of the task then that task is lost.
What kind of mechanism could prevent that so we can reprocess abandoned tasks?

Comment: Are you using Redis Streams?

Comment: No, I'm not. Using lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ZSET to solve this issue

**Pop operation**

- Add to ZSET with expiry time
- Remove from list

**Ack Operation**

- Remove from ZSET

**Worker**

You need to run a scheduled worker that will move items from ZSET to list if they are expired

Read it in detail, how I did in Rqueue https://medium.com/@sonus21/introducing-rqueue-redis-queue-d344f5c36e1b

Github Code: https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue

Answer (score 0):

There is no `EXPIRE` for set or zset members and there is no atomic operation to pop from zset and push to list. So I ended writing this lua script which runs atomically.

First I add a task to the `executing-tasks` zset with a timestamp score (`(new Date()).valueOf()` in javascript):

`ZADD 1619028226766 executing-tasks`

Then I run the script:

`EVAL [THE SCRIPT] 2 executing-tasks tasks 1619028196766`

If the task is more than 30 seconds old it will be sent to the `tasks` list. If not, it will be sent back to the `executing-tasks` zset.

Here is the script

```
  local source = KEYS[1]
  local destination = KEYS[2]
  local min_score = ARGV[1]
  local popped = redis.call('zpopmin', source)
  local id = popped[1]
  local score = popped[2]
  if table.getn(popped) > 0 then
    if score < min_score then
      redis.call('rpush', destination, id)
      return { "RESTORED", id }
    else
      redis.call('zadd', source, score, id)
      return { "SENT_BACK", id }
    end
  end
  return { "NOTHING_DONE" }
```